# Update angular model after 60 seconds

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-scope

How do I get my model to update automatically after 60 seconds?

I have an array in `$scope.tweets` that contains a list of tweets. I would like `$scope.currentTweet` to pop a tweet off the array every 60 seconds.

Is there is a particular way to do this in angular?

Comment: I like your bio man :D thumbs up!

Comment: @FiidoFirdauz haha, thanks 

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes you can. AngularJS has $interval for you.

1. Inject $interval into your controller.
2. Register it for calling an update function every 60s.

**Example:**

```
myApp.controller('MyCtrl', ['$scope', '$interval', function($scope, $interval){
    $scope.tweets = [];
    $scope.currentTweet = null;
    var myUpdater = $interval(function(){
        $scope.currentTweet = $scope.tweets.pop();
    }, 60*1000);

    //And you can cancel the interval anytime you want by calling this:
    $interval.cancel(myUpdate);
})
```

Comment: The function passed to `$interval` is automatically wrapped in `$apply`. Calling `$scope.$apply()` from within it will cause a "digest in progress" error.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the [$interval](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$interval) service, which is Angular's wrapper around the native [setInterval](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowTimers/setInterval) function.

```
$interval(function () {
    $scope.currentTweet = $scope.tweets.shift();
}, 60 * 1000);
```